# "Appealing for" or "appealing to"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, present-participles

Are there guidelines for when to use *to* or *for* with *appealing*?

I was writing this sentence: '... choose a time that is appealing to you', and then thought it was likely *for*, but either seems to make sense or "sound right".

Any advice?

Comment: Advice? Drop the two words altogether. "...choose a time that is appealing." (I'll bet the reader will be able to figure out who that time should appeal to).

Comment: @J.R. Fair enough as a practical solution - but as a general rule - if I did use either, which is correct?

Comment: that's why I put that as a comment, not as a question - but, if you look carefully,  I did indicate which preposition would be _generally_ preferred.

Comment: It's almost always [*appeal to*; here's an NGram showing you.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appeal+to%2C+appeal+for%2C+appealing+to%2C+appealing+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: What J.R. said. Native speakers simply wouldn't be likely to use *appealing* in the context of an [appointment?] time. It would practically always be *suitable* or *convenient*. But as JLG says, if you are going to use *appealing* (in some more suitable context), you'd normally follow it by **to**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Appealing to' and 'Appealing for' are different.

One appeals to someone (a person, an institution, a court, a foundation etc) to do something.

The other appeals for something ( a benefit, a ruling, funds, help, etc).

> I am appealing to you to accept my answer.
>
> I am appealing for points as I do not have many.

'... choose a time that is appealing to you'

'... choose a time that is appealing for you'

I would prefer the first example, but the second example is comprehensible.  I would prefer:

'.....choose a time that appeals to you' or '.... choose a time that is convenient for you'.

Answer (score 2):

Two different sense of *appeal* are involved here, taking different prepositions

1. **ask (for), request** ... One appeals *to* someone (a person, an institution, a court, a foundation &c) *to* do something or *for* something (a boon, a benefit, a ruling, funds, help &c)

> I am appealing *to* you to accept my answer.
>   I am appealing *to* others *for* their votes.

1. **attract, please** ... Something appeals *to* someone

> The idea that you may be satisfied with my answer is appealing *to* me.

Comment: In both cases you are using `to`. Would be great to have an example pointing out the usage of `for`.

Answer (score 1):

In that context, I'd use "to". If I find something appealing, it is appealing *to* me. If I need help from someone and a third party talks to the person that can provide it, they are appealing "for" me. It's a different use of the word, but that's the connotation that "to" and "for" bring out. (at least to me.)

Answer (score 1):

When you say "appealing for", that makes me think that you wrote something nice, and it's for me. When you say "appealing to", that makes me think that it's nice *to me*, meaning that *I like it*.

Examples:

*I cooked something impeccably appealing for you!*

This means that the chef cooked something that looked nice to him, but not exactly to the eater. It's not exactly a direct judging.

*I cooked something* **that's** *impeccably appealing to you!*

This sentence it extremely directed towards the eater. It basically displays the chef's take on the outcome of the eater's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Appealing for should be followed by the purpose of making request. E.g., Appealing for Bonafide Certificate.
But, appealing to means (you are requesting a person to do something for you). E.g., Appealing to HM to Issue a Bonafide Certificate. (to HM) can be deleted from the sentence, but it will be understood that you are talking to specific person and requesting him to do something for you.